# Can I pass local variable in observable callbacks

Tags: android, kotlin, observable

My pseudo code below, I'm curious if Object instance o remains valid for the entirety of class `Some`'s existence.

Would for every observable callback `secondMethod(o)`, the `o` remains in memory and isn't garbage collected while the `Some` class and observable callback is alive.

This runs fine locally but somehow seems fishy.

```
class Some {
   val observable = Observable()
   fun method(){
      val o = Object()
      observable.observe { it => { secondMethod(o)}}
   }
   fun secondMethod(o: Object){
      println("object o is valid as long as Some class is in memory? ${o.toString()}")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither Kotlin nor Java lets you do something squirrelly where you could potentially ever be working with a dead reference with undefined results (with the exception of things you can do with JNI and ByteBuffers).

`o` in your example is completely independent from anything in the Some class, so it's perfectly fine to pass to the callback. It becomes *captured* by the callback, so its reference is held by the callback instance. It's irrelevant that Some is holding a reference to Observable. Even if Observable was held by some other class and outlives the Some instance, `o` would still be captured.

You can even mark `o` as a `var` and you're allowed to pass it to the callback. This isn't allowed in Java, but in Kotlin it is--the capture holds a reference to the whole mutable variable so it could potentially be captured by multiple different callbacks and they would see changes that the other ones are making to which object the variable is referencing.

You can also use class properties in your callback, which is quite common to do in any callback if you're doing anything beyond just logging. When you do this, the whole instance of `Some` would be captured by the callback. This is a common way memory leaks can happen. If a class captures itself in a callback that it passes to a longer-lived class, then it is leaked along with everything it has a reference to.